# Лямбда выражения: помогите разобраться

Tags: c#, linq

Объясните, пожалуйста, данный код подробно если несложно, просто изучаю недавно c#.
Даже с аннотацией немого понять. Учу язык пару месяцев.
Заранее прошу прощения за размытый вопрос.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using CodeCamper.Data.Contracts;

namespace CodeCamper.Data
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A maker of Code Camper Repositories.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// An instance of this class contains repository factory functions for different types.
    /// Each factory function takes an EF <see cref="DbContext"/> and returns
    /// a repository bound to that DbContext.
    /// <para>
    /// Designed to be a "Singleton", configured at web application start with
    /// all of the factory functions needed to create any type of repository.
    /// Should be thread-safe to use because it is configured at app start,
    /// before any request for a factory, and should be immutable thereafter.
    /// </para>
    /// </remarks>
    public class RepositoryFactories
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Return the runtime Code Camper repository factory functions,
        /// each one is a factory for a repository of a particular type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// MODIFY THIS METHOD TO ADD CUSTOM CODE CAMPER FACTORY FUNCTIONS
        /// </remarks>
        private IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>> GetCodeCamperFactories()
        {
            return new Dictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>>
                {
                   {typeof(IAttendanceRepository), dbContext => new AttendanceRepository(dbContext)},
                   {typeof(IPersonsRepository), dbContext => new PersonsRepository(dbContext)},
                   {typeof(ISessionsRepository), dbContext => new SessionsRepository(dbContext)},
                };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor that initializes with runtime Code Camper repository factories
        /// </summary>
        public RepositoryFactories()  
        {
            _repositoryFactories = GetCodeCamperFactories();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor that initializes with an arbitrary collection of factories
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="factories">
        /// The repository factory functions for this instance. 
        /// </param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This ctor is primarily useful for testing this class
        /// </remarks>
        public RepositoryFactories(IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>> factories )
        {
            _repositoryFactories = factories;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the repository factory function for the type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type serving as the repository factory lookup key.</typeparam>
        /// <returns>The repository function if found, else null.</returns>
        /// <remarks>
        /// The type parameter, T, is typically the repository type 
        /// but could be any type (e.g., an entity type)
        /// </remarks>
        public Func<DbContext, object> GetRepositoryFactory<T>()
        {

            Func<DbContext, object> factory;
            _repositoryFactories.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out factory);
            return factory;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the factory for <see cref="IRepository{T}"/> where T is an entity type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The root type of the repository, typically an entity type.</typeparam>
        /// <returns>
        /// A factory that creates the <see cref="IRepository{T}"/>, given an EF <see cref="DbContext"/>.
        /// </returns>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Looks first for a custom factory in <see cref="_repositoryFactories"/>.
        /// If not, falls back to the <see cref="DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory{T}"/>.
        /// You can substitute an alternative factory for the default one by adding
        /// a repository factory for type "T" to <see cref="_repositoryFactories"/>.
        /// </remarks>
        public Func<DbContext, object> GetRepositoryFactoryForEntityType<T>() where T : class
        {
            return GetRepositoryFactory<T>() ?? DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory<T>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Default factory for a <see cref="IRepository{T}"/> where T is an entity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the repository's root entity</typeparam>
        protected virtual Func<DbContext, object> DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory<T>() where T : class
        {
            return dbContext => new EFRepository<T>(dbContext);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the dictionary of repository factory functions.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// A dictionary key is a System.Type, typically a repository type.
        /// A value is a repository factory function
        /// that takes a <see cref="DbContext"/> argument and returns
        /// a repository object. Caller must know how to cast it.
        /// </remarks>
        private readonly IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>> _repositoryFactories;

    }
}
```

Comment: Я лично сомневаюсь, что здесь найдется человек, который будет подробно объяснять вам этот код. Попробуйте задать 4-5 конкретных вопросов, а дальше что-нибудь придумаем.

Comment: @Лщтик_хочет_кушать Что, комментариев много?

Comment: @фдexlz Ну вцелом — довольно круто написано. Такие комментарии maintain'ить, конечно, задолбаешься, но на [всю сборку CodeCamper.Data](https://github.com/NicholasMurray/CodeCamper/tree/master/CodeCamper.Data) приятно смотреть.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать извиняюсь за ошибку в наборе. Но ник -- длинный

Comment: @alexlz И меня простите, в таком случае :) А к чему все-таки был комментарий про "много комментариев"? Он на тему того, что в предложенном коде комментариев / xml-документации больше, чем, собственно, кода?

Comment: Извиняться не за что, вполне нормальная реакция не мою ошибку. А про комментарии -- читать трудно. А что такое CodeCamper я могу только поискать в интернете. Да и то не за 10-20 минут. Так что это просто реакция на необычный текст. Кстати, кто его генерит? Или это всё же пишется руками для последующей обработки?

И ещё вопрос: как в комментарий вставить ссылку?

Comment: @alexlz по поводу ссылки в комментарии - точно так же как и в ответ. Попробуйте вставить ссылку в ответ, и посмотрите, что сгенерируется при этом. Будет что-то такое: ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/CWYO6hD.png

Comment: @alexlz, ссылка в комментарии это

    [текст](URL)

вот такая конструкция

Comment: Здесь реализация патерна фабрики объектов, фронт-енд для запросов к бд. просто не понимаю rivate IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>> GetCodeCamperFactories(). Если несложно объясните

Comment: Ну смотрите. `Func<DbContext, object>` — это функция, с аргументом типа `DbContext` и результатом типа `object` (то есть функция с сигнатурой `object f(DbContext ctx)`.

Выражение

    dbContext => new AttendanceRepository(dbContext)

есть анонимная функция. Оно равнозначно тому, что где-то объявлена функция

    object f(DbContext dbContext) { return new AttendanceRepository(dbContext); }

а вместо лямбда-выражения использовано имя этой функции.